# WordPress PayPal integration for subscription

Tags: paypal, wordpress

I am currently working on developing a plugin for subscription in WordPress.
I have integrated PayPal with the plugin but the problem is that how can I get the payment status from PayPal?

I have set return parameter to my subscription page but it does not receive payment status and other parameters from PayPal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use [IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/) for that.  It will POST data to your application about every transaction that hits the account so you can process them accordingly, automatically and in real-time.

You can use [PayPal IPN for WordPress](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-ipn-wordpress/) to get up and running quickly.  It comes with [lots of different hooks](https://www.angelleye.com/paypal-ipn-wordpress-hooks/) to trigger your own stuff based on different transaction types or payment status (note: these links are to my own website).

Comment: I've added a small disclaimer to make it clear to readers that these links are to your own website - I think that is in keeping with the values generally discussed on _Meta_. Hope that's OK.